# Oracle triggers - what value does :new have when nothing is passed?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

As in the question - what value will `:new` take when the update omits the column referenced in trigger completely?

I am trying to debug a stored procedure which fires a trigger on update which uses a function accepting `:new` field with `DATE` value. However, the update I am running does not update referenced column.

Will the trigger use the value stored in the table on which the update is run? Or will it take it from somewhere else?

Comment: Where else do you think the database would get the value from?

Comment: I'm quite new to PL/SQL so I expect anything to happen :) It's not like everything follows simple logic in Oracle, yesterday I was struggling because calling TO_DATE on date column yields rather surprising results :)

Comment: Well you shouldn't expect "anything".  Oracle database transactions are entirely predictable, even with triggers.  Later on you'll come across the "mutating table" exception, which is what happens when we code a stupid trigger whose outcome Oracle cannot predict.

Comment: As for your date problem, that just shows you're using a very old version of the database.  It used to be the case that Oracle hurled when we applied a TO_DATE to a column or variable which had a DATE datatype.  Which is understandable because TO_DATE() clearly requires a string parameter.   However, it was such a common howler that eventually Oracle overloaded the function, so in 11g (and I think 10g) we can run `select to_date(sysdate) from dual` without an error.  Doesn't stop it being a daft thing to do.

Comment: I can run to_date on a date, the problem is it yields gibberish (usually something like '0013-01-01'). As for the reason to use it, I was truncating timestamps with it, which when I think of it was a dumb way to do it anyway :) Well, I pay the price for forgetting to use trunc() :)

Comment: That's not gibberish, just bad data: someone's explicitly populating  dates without the century, which Oracle then represents as `00`.

Comment: Well, the dates in the column I'm talking about are in form '2013-01-01 12:00:00', so when running to_date(col, 'YYYY-MM-DD') I would expect it to return exactly that minus the time...

Comment: This is running too long.  You can ask it as a new question if you like.  Or we could take it to chat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the column is omited in the update statment, then the `:NEW.column` value is the same as the `:OLD.column` value. And that is the value that was stored in the table before the update statment was run

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation is not entirely clear](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_trigger.htm#i2064286) about this, but `:NEW` and `:OLD` indicate the version of *the current row* .

So, `:NEW.col23` indicates the value of that column in the new version of the row.  If the transaction hasn't changed the value of that column then it will be the same as  `:OLD.col23`.  Indeed we can use this to code a test in our triggers to see whether an update has changed the value in a column:

```
if :NEW.col23 = :OLD.col23 then
   --  value not changed
```